# svg spinner created with styled components sharing same color

Tags: reactjs, svg, styled-components

I'm playing around with **styled-components** and trying to create a svg circle spinner component. Everything is great except when I try to use the component multiple times in same page then every component is using the same **strokeColor** from the last one. The other props **strokeWidth** is working fine though.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Spinner from "./Spinner";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Spinner strokeColor="#000000" strokeWidth={2} />
      <Spinner strokeColor="red" strokeWidth={1} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

What am I missing here?

Here's the codesandbox demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pyo8kox787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see is that you've created your `keyframes` as regular css and not with styled-components `keyframes` helper.
From the styled-components [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#animations):

> CSS animations with @keyframes aren't scoped to a single component but
>   you still don't want them to be global to avoid name collisions. This
>   is why we export a keyframes helper which will generate a unique
>   instance that you can use throughout your app

As for what I can tell, the keyframes is created for the last component being rendered as they aren't scoped to the component.
The fix is using the `keyframes` helper like this:

```
import styled, {keyframes} from "styled-components";

const colorKeyFrames = keyframes`
0% {
      stroke: ${props => props.color || "#ffffff"};
    }
    40% {
      stroke: ${props => props.color || "#ffffff"};
    }
    66% {
      stroke: ${props => props.color || "#ffffff"};
    }
    80%,
    90% {
      stroke: ${props => props.color || "#ffffff"};
    }
`;
```

And a fix for your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vy250zv6n0).
Keep in mind, you'll need to fix it for every keyframes you have there.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for pointing me out. That's what I was looking for.